# What terminology is neutral in meta-ethics?

Tags: terminology, metaethics

Meta-ethics concerns whether at least some ethical judgments are what one might call facts. In particular, a cognitivist who subscribes to realism, rather than the error theory or something similar, holds that they express believed propositions which are sometimes true. As soon as they try to defend this view, they'll need to discuss the relationships between

1. "things whose status as facts aren't in meta-ethical dispute because of logical or empirical bases for them" and
2. "things whose potential status as further facts is part of what we're debating".

In short, the "is" & "ought" as Hume construed them.

What names can we give these two things that don't presuppose any specific view in meta-ethics? In particular, simply calling 1 "facts" seems inappropriate for this, as it implies 2 (whatever they be called), by contrast, don't comprise facts. I'm sure the need for terminology that doesn't have this problem has led someone to suggest something more workable, but I've not encountered it.

Popper certainly didn't. In *Facts, Standards and Truth: A Further Criticism of Relativism*, his 1961 addendum to *The Open Society and Its Enemies*, Popper talks a lot about a dualism between facts and standards, which, on my best attempt to read it without finding him contradicting himself, would make these his terms for 1 and 2. Therefore, I suspect a "neutral" pair of terms postdates 1961.

A further clarifying edit, to address the close vote: I'm sorry if this question *came across as* opinion-based, but literally all I want to know is whether anyone's invented an alternate to "is statements and ought statements" that doesn't suggest anti-realism. That's a factual question about terminology in the literature. I'm assuming from people's responses that they haven't, or at least not very famously.

Comment: From what I understand (see [Eidlin's paper](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1965430)), Popper's fact/standard dualism is similar to the usual fact/value distinction, between natural (non-moral) facts and norms, the difference is that he admits rational criticism of standards themselves. So his "facts" do not apply to either 1 or 2. I do not think there is any standard terminology for distinguishing 1 and 2 (mainly because 1 is essentially empty), but people may talk of non-controversial vs controversial moral principles if need be.

Comment: @Conifold Why would you say 1 is essentially empty? Meta-ethicists tend to agree, for example, that observable effects of policies are factual; those are the kind of "is" Hume says can't get an "ought".

Comment: It is hard to tell whether what you mean in 1,2 are first order moral facts or meta-principles. The post suggests the former, but the example in the comment is of the latter. Either way, "*One answer often offered is that, at a suitably abstract level, there are premises or principles that everyone in fact accepts... But of course such claims hardly do much work*", [SEP, Moral Epistemology](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/metaethics/#MorEpi).

Comment: I've edited the question to make my definition clearer.

Comment: J.G. Comment noted, answer withdrawn.

Comment: I've been puddling with answering this question, and now I'm debating whether I should add a close vote. The problem is that even to begin answering the question I'd have to deconstruct the way you're using the term 'fact', and I'm not certain I can do it in a reasonable post size. I feel like you've taken the 'beltway' approach here, driving in big circles around the question without actually getting into it, and I'm not certain it's wise of fruitful for me to take the wheel. Hmph.

Comment: @TedWrigley If an alternative to "fact" would have had the meaning I intended you're welcome to tell me or even edit the question, but the fact that people keep discussing that aspect of it suggests to me that the terminology I'm seeking doesn't exist. Literally all I need is a replacement of "is", and possibly also "ought", in "can you get an ought from an is?", and I'll be sated, regardless of your concerns.

Comment: Well, philosophically that's confusing. *Is* and *ought* reflect two distinct modes of human cognition — description and choice — and this is as true for physics as it is for ethics. It's one thing to describe what nuclear fission *is*, and quite another to decide whether or not we *ought* to build a nuclear bomb, right? I don't see a problem that calls for a new terminology. Maybe if you could explain the problem you see?

Comment: @TedWrigley The problem is that this terminology is used in debating a metaphysical question, not merely to discuss modes of cognition, so "is" becomes shorthand for "things whose status is the same under moral realism as under moral anti-realism", whereas "ought" becomes shorthand for "things whose status is more similar to that of is-statements under moral realism than under moral anti-realism". So it would be helpful if the second name didn't give the impression that the moral anti-realist's victory is a *fait accompli*.

Comment: You should real the first couple of paragraphs of this SEP article — https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/moral-anti-realism/ — which basically says that moral anti-realism is defined in terms of moral realism, but moral realism is so inadequately defined that contrasting it says almost nothing at all. And then we get into the problem of Durkheim's "Social Facts", which is a likely place to start looking for moral facts, but that just puts the fox in the henhouse. I mean, do you accept "social facts" as facts?

Comment: @TedWrigley I think that, regardless of whether we end up considering them facts *after* arguing about it, calling certain things "social facts" *before* we do that is as presumptuous in a realist direction as is using the terms is/ought in the anti-realist one. Thanks for your link; it makes sense of _why_ the terminology I asked about hasn't been invented (albeit with a very disappointing reason, but the field today is what it is).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105051/discussion-between-ted-wrigley-and-j-g).

Answer (score -1):

You say

> Meta-ethics concerns whether at least some ethical judgments are what one might call facts.

Whereas Wikipedias article on  [meta-ethics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta-ethics):

> Meta-ethics is the branch of ethics that seeks to understand the nature of ethical properties, statements, attitudes, and judgments. Meta-ethics is one of the three branches of ethics generally studied by philosophers, the others being normative ethics and applied ethics.
>
> While normative ethics addresses such questions as "What should I do?", evaluating specific practices and principles of action, meta-ethics addresses questions such as "What is goodness?" and "How can we tell what is good from what is bad?", seeking to understand the nature of ethical properties and evaluations.

Thus not really very different from traditional ethics...